# How to send the SIGINT under Mac(GUI Application)?

Tags: macos

I am testing a code which respond to SIGINT. I am using Mac, is Ctrl-C to send the SIGINT? I tried, it seems no response.

Comment: Are you running a command-line tool in Terminal? Or are you running a GUI application? In a shell in Terminal, yes, Control-C will send SIGINT.

Comment: I am in a GUI application, how to send SIGINT?

Comment: I also see Control-C is not sending SIGINT even in a terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Activity Monitor to send signals to processes. Select the process in the process list and then choose View > Send Signal to Process. In the resulting sheet, select SIGINT from the pop-up menu and hit the Send button.

Answer (score 2):

First, find the name of the process. So, if you think it is called something like *"monkey"*, try this in **Terminal**:

```
pgrep -i monkey
```

and see if that tells you some process ids. If it does, you can then do:

```
pkill -SIGINT -i monkey
```